# Spring MVC check username in db before submission

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

I am making a web application using Spring MVC and jsp. I am quite new to this and really struggling to find an approach to validating a username from DB before submitting the form. Here is a demo of the kind of thing am looking for http://www.bitrepository.com/demo/username-checker/

Would appreciate any help given. Thank you

Comment: you can start by following this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-4-mvc-ajax-hello-world-example/

Comment: This looks really helpful. Correct me if am wrong but the tutorial looks like the validation is done when you press the search button. If so then would it be possible to do the validation before pressing the search button?

Comment: To be exact, In that tutorial, the ajax call is triggered on `onsubmit` event (not on `onclick` event). So you just need to change it to whatever you like. Find the list of possible DOM events [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp) (plain js) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_events.asp) (jquery version)

Comment: Thank you very much that has helped me a lot @YohanesGultom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed this this tutorial:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-4-mvc-ajax-hello-world-example/

Thank you very much @YohanesGultom

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of answers if you search "Spring MVC form validation" on Google. For example, spring official tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

Another example on codejava.net: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-form-validation-example-with-bean-validation-api

Comment: I am already doing form validation when user clicks submit. I wanted it so that the db check is done in the background for username availabilty without the user having to press the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

you can check username by jquery validation

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      required: true,
       remote: {
            url: 'checkUserName',
            data: { userName: $('#username').val()},
            dataFilter: function(data) {
                var json = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(data);
            }
    }
  },
  messages: {
    email: {
      required: "This field is required",
      remote: "Email address already in use. Please use other email."
    }
  }
});
```

and in your  controller add this method :

```
@requestMapping("checkUserName")
@responseBody
public boolean  checkUser(@requestParam("userName") String userName){

 return // method return bolean if user exist or non in database.
}
```